# Phabricator/SVN - What's the best way to manage multiple subdirectories of a repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, phabricator

We've just started using Phabricator and are in the process of integrating our SVN repositories into the system. One repository is kind of a "mega" repository, about 4GB in size, and housing many small projects. What I would like to do is separate them out in Phabricator so that instead of having the one mega repository, I would have a separate repository in Phabricator for each project. I would like to do this without modifying the existing repository and actually separating it out.

I believe I can do this by setting "import only" on each repository to `customer/small-project`, etc. and in fact just did this for the first small project, but it appears to be importing the entire 4.1GB repo because it is taking forever. What I want to avoid is Phabricator importing the ENTIRE mega repo for each subproject for obvious reasons (disk space usage, general performance).

Is there a way to avoid this? Or will Phabricator be smart enough to not permanently store all those duplicate files in the system, allowing me to continue on in the way I have just started?

Comment: Excepted if you have large files to store, which seems to be a strong possibility according to the 4 GB, you would benefit a lot to migrate this mega repo into small Git repos (even with the different extensions offered in the market, including GLS or git annex, Git isn't really comfortable to use with large files). I would keep any project with large files in the SVN, and move everything else into Git independent repositories as a part of your Phabricator migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we figured out the issue. I did not specify the "Import Only" directory until **after** I started the import, which caused Phabricator to import all the files for the entire repo. We deleted the repo from Phabricator and then specified the "Import Only" directory **before** starting the import. The import ran MUCH faster and only the desired files were added.

Be careful when doing Phabricator SVN imports that you choose the right data to import before starting the import process!